# laravel 5.4 Token based Oauth implementation

Tags: laravel

Laravel 5.4 : passport is enough to implement Oauth2 or else we need Dingo package?

what is the difference between of oauth2 and Dingo ?

Answer (score 1):

**Oauth2**

A simple service provider that makes Laravel Passport work with Lumen
 Only require Oauth2 implementation to achieve Password Authentication

**Dingo**

Its Multiple Authentication Adapters,
  To implement multiple authentication like Oauth2, JWT, Authorization, Basic authentication